# socket2=accept(socket1,&client,&len_client); - при компиляции всплывают предупреждения

Tags: c, сеть

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main (void)
{
    int socket1,socket2;
    socket1=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    struct sockaddr_in net,client;
    net.sin_family=AF_INET;
    net.sin_port=32222;
    net.sin_addr.s_addr="127.0.0.1";

    bind(socket1,(struct sockaddr*)&net,sizeof(net));
    listen(socket1,3);
    int len_client=sizeof(client);
    socket2=accept(socket1,&client,&len_client);
    return 0 ;
}
```

---

При компилировании данного кода всплывают предупреждения:

---

`lessons88.c:18:25: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘accept’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  socket2=accept(socket1,&client,&len_client);`

`lessons88.c:18:33: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 3 of ‘accept’ differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
  socket2=accept(socket1,&client,&len_client);`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Что я неправильно сделал? Объясните пожалуйста и если вам не лень то объясните ещё, почему всплывает предупреждение на 13-ой строке?

---

`lessons88.c:13:21: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  net.sin_addr.s_addr="127.0.0.1";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде все достаточно очевидно - повсеместно используются несовместимые типы данных. `net.sin_addr.s_addr="127.0.0.1";` - присвоение целому числу указателя на char const, передаваемые аргументы не совпадают с требуемыми функцией `accept`. Помимо этого, `sockaddr_in` используется потенциально частично неинициализированная, ее необходимо предварительно занулять. Номер порта необходимо задавать с сетевым порядком байт. Обработка ошибок отсутствует.

Comment: Как это не совпадают? Вот же требуемые аргументы: `int accept(int sockfd, void *addr, int *addrlen);` - ссылка на источник https://www.rsdn.org/article/unix/sockets.xml

Comment: @name `int accept(int socket, struct sockaddr * address, socklen_t * address_len);` [posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/accept.html)

Comment: Спасибо)) А как вы предложите мне записать айпишник в `net.sin_addr.s_addr`? И зачем занулять структуру? В нее же все равно записывается адрес сокета клиента.

Comment: @name там есть функция для конвертирования строк в числовые значения адреса, а занулять необходимо чтобы в ней не было неинициализированных полей. Еще имейте ввиду, что номер порта необходимо задавать с сетевым порядком байт

Comment: Еще раз спасибо, последнее не понял, а зачем их вообще иницилизировать?

Comment: @name обращение к неинициализированным полям является неопределенным поведением. а в этой структуре может быть куда больше полей, чем у вас потом заполняется

Comment: Хорошо)) Понял:-)

Comment: @name, второй аргумент в `accept` это результат его работы, на самом деле структуру `client` можно не обнулять, а вот третий нужно инициализировать размером второго (вы правильно сделали) / Кроме всего, результат `bind()` всегда надо поверять.

Comment: @avp, хорошо, буду знать, спасибо за ответ)